# Multiply the rows with dates in aws athena

Tags: amazon-athena

I'm new to aws athena.

Is there a way to get the expected output from this input?

**INPUT** (csv file has following input)

```
DATE (yyyymmdd) | ip  | FINISHED ( 1:finished; 0: not finish)
2017-01-01      | 111 | 1    
2017-01-01      | 222 | 1    
2017-01-02      | 333 | 1    
2017-01-03      | 444 | 1
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
DATE (yyyymmdd) | ip  | FINISHED ( 1:finished; 0: not finish)    
2017-01-01      | 111 | 1    
2017-01-01      | 222 | 1    
2017-01-01      | 333 | 0    
2017-01-01      | 444 | 0    
2017-01-02      | 111 | 1    
2017-01-02      | 222 | 1    
2017-01-02      | 333 | 1    
2017-01-02      | 444 | 0   
2017-01-03      | 111 | 1    
2017-01-03      | 222 | 1    
2017-01-03      | 333 | 1    
2017-01-03      | 444 | 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is example query how to do it:

```
select t1."DATE (yyyymmdd)",t2.ip from
(SELECT "DATE (yyyymmdd)" FROM tab1 group by "DATE (yyyymmdd)") t1,
(SELECT ip FROM tab2 group by ip) t2
```

In this "select" is used cartesian join, so you cannot apply this to big data set,  because there will occur  the performance issues.